# Reviewer mistakenly marking well-intentioned edit suggestions as spam

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam, review-abuse

I ran into a fellow reviewer today who flagged a [perfectly legitimate edit](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9033129) as spam/vandalism. That's a step beyond merely making a bad call about whether an edit should be allowed through, as that could mis-train the filter and perhaps mess up someone's account. So I looked through the last few pages of their review history and found several other instances of the same sort of mistake. [Sometimes](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9032495) they [marked edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8963757) that were [dubiously applicable](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9016359), but even on [those](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8964469), there's a definite difference between a merely unwise or excessive edit, and outright spamming or vandalism. And sometimes there seems [no real reason to reject at all](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8965049), like [this OP-approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8979058), or this [typo fix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8950171), or this [title fix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8950309), or this [code import](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8950360).

If I'm correct, I expect a diamond should gently correct their misconception of that rejection reason's purpose. Or, given the sheer number of these in the first, what, seven pages, perhaps a time off reviewing.

Comment: If you mark everything as spam, you'll never fail the audit. Genius!

Comment: @Rob: I did think of that, but that's not the only rejection reason they use, and they do approve a fair number.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to attention - it's been handled.

Comment: @JonClements: Awesome! Can't complain about the response time on this!

Comment: Isn't this what the "in need of moderator intervention" flag is for. You don't need to call out a specific user on meta then either.

Comment: @Ben FWIW details provided here wouldn't fit into flag message (it's limited to 500 0r 600 chars). If it wouldn't be so, then I would definitely agree about flag being better option

Comment: @gnat A link to the user’s profile and one or two examples are normally enough when raising a moderator attention flag. This should never has been posted here actually.

Comment: @idmean not true in my experience. Even if something from the user in question can be flagged, a couple of external links and a bit of explanation (but not enough) soon sucks up all those characters. Too little for the mods, naturally "no evidence..." comes back. Big frustration.

Comment: @BillWoodger Well, in my experience every time I raised a moderator flag it was marked as helpful and the user was no longer able to continue (with whatever he was doing). And I always had enough characters.

Comment: @idmean an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229486/218565. I happened to be looking here when you posted your comment because I was considering a Feature Request to make the box bigger. It is limited to 500 for flagging questions/answers and 200 for comments. Fine for simple things, sure, but other than the "contact us" (which doesn't go to Mods (directly) anyway, there is no way, at times, of providing "enough" information. If you've spent a few hours investigating something, to be circumstantially certain, you want to be able to present that, not a post-it note and hope that a mod ha

Comment: s the same amount of time to duplicate your research. Irony intended, even if just a comment.

Comment: _And sometimes there seems no real reason to reject at all_ - I'm guessing it was either the horizontal scrolling or that the edit was incomplete since it left in the "I'm new, please help" type text. I almost asked a separate meta question on that one though because it certainly isn't easier to read unformatted.

Comment: @BillWoodger: where I have run out of space e.g. when listing URLs of a voting ring, I've used a private Gist as a supplemental.

Comment: @halfer there's a useful idea. Now I just need to find out what a Gist is. I guess anything which is private but access to others can be granted on a limited basis. OK. No Feature Request. Thanks.

Comment: @BillWoodger ...another trick to consider is to use own deleted answer or question as a "buffer" to fill the data and then refer it in the flag message. I keep a bunch of tricks like that in my pockets for the case if I need to flag something that is both _big_ and _delicate_. But frankly, reporting an outright review abuse doesn't look worth such trouble to me and I wouldn't hesitate to bring it to meta - just because it's simpler

Comment: @gnat Interesting. I like it, except I don't know who, and when, someone can see my deleted questions even without a link. Answers I assume that 10k+ who happen to look at the question it is on, would see it. Can 10k+ see it from my profile? Presumably I'd also get a badge for asking my first question, another for deleting it, another for editing it. I like the idea, and also want to know how to pick your pockets for other tricks :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger 10Kers can see deleted questions and answers, so you better use these for stuff that you just don't want to expose _too_ wide. As for communicating truly sensitive stuff, "Contact Us" is hard to beat. I tried it once, works like a charm. By the way Jon Ericson has [series of four articles](http://jericson.github.io/2015/03/13/customer-support-1.html "first article, links to next one") describing how it works, quite interesting reading

Comment: @BillWoodger: a Gist is a pasteboard system, usually for the purposes of code/configuration data, owned by GitHub. Any pasteboard with a "private URL" feature will do here. (I'm not necessarily opposed to a feature request, just outlining how I've circumvented the length restriction in the past).

Comment: @gnat thanks, interesting to see the background. Can't find the edit link to fix the typos, though...

Comment: @gnat: I'm sitting on another big data dump of (less serious) suggested-edit missteps by a couple of users. Would you recommend sticking that in a deleted answer?

Comment: @BSMP: Could be, but keep in mind I've seen a number of reviewers reject edits that take out noise like "I'm new, please help", so there's a certain lack of consistency there.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes, absolutely. Consider that moderators _can_ comment on deleted posts if needed. And that you can "address" their comments by post edits if needed. That makes it not only (semi)private data buffer but also a (semi)private communication channel. And single flag with link to it can bootstrap whole process. As sort of example, see [how I used my deleted answer for privately drafting some feature request](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/5542/2) (it was then reviewed by 10kers, undeleted, collaboratively edited and reposted to MSE but that's a different story:)